# Setting up Tabula on a remote server

Tags: tabula

new here. I'm currently trying to set up an implementation of [Tabula](https://tabula.technology/) on a Windows Server. I've set up a non-standard port to run the service (port 8090) and have set up firewall rules, but I can't seem to make it work. I've also been assured by the hosting company that they don't filter ports so all possible ports would have been blocked by either the router or the machine itself.

I've also set up port forwarding (with similar settings that work on the router). Didn't work.

I've also tried using port 80, then temporarily turning off the Apache server on that machine so it would free up that port. To no avail, alas.

I've also tried Proxypass, with the same failed results:

```
<Location /tab>
ProxyPass http://release.123-246.com:8090/
ProxyPassReverse http://release.123-246.com:8090/
</Location>
```

It works on localhost (127.0.0.1:8090) and local network address (192.168.0.4:8090, but only from within the machine's browser) but can't seem to make it work on live (78.46.210.12:8090)

Pretty sure I'm missing something, but I don't know what it is. Help please? I'm welcome to different approaches on this.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that Tabula is listening on the appropriate interface?

The version of Tabula that is packaged as a Windows application might not bind to the interface fronted by your reverse proxy.

Try this command to make Tabula listen on all available interfaces:

```
jruby -G -r jbundler -S rackup -o 0.0.0.0 config.ru
```

Comment: Hi,
I'm running Tabula from the command line:
        `java -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Xms256M -Xmx1024M -Dwarbler.port=8090 -jar tabula.jar`
I'm not familiar with the JRuby command, where do I run this? Do I need to install JRuby to run it?

Comment: That works too. That command should bind the Tabula webserver to `0.0.0.0`. If not, try adding `-Dwarbler.host=0.0.0.0`